# JavaScript Multiple image upload validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I need your help. My script validate images resolution before sending form.

The problem is that when script should stop because one or more photos is bigger than maximum resolution. It's not happening.

var err is counting number of bad resolution photos, but on the end, i dont know why it is always 0.

Any ideas?

```
jQuery("form").submit( function( e ) {
                var form = this;
                e.preventDefault();

                    var photos = document.getElementById('imgInp');
                    var howmany = photos.files.length;
                    var err = 0;

                    var img = new Array();

                    for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {               

                        if (photos.files[i]) {

                            img[i] = new Image();
                            img[i].src = window.URL.createObjectURL( photos.files[i] );

                            img[i].onload = function() {

                                window.URL.revokeObjectURL( this.src );

                                    if( this.width < 1281 && this.height < 1025 ) {                                                                           

                                    } else {                                           

                                        alert('Zdjęcie jest zbyt duże');
                                        err++;

                                    }
                            };

                        } else {

                        form.submit();

                        }                           

                    }

                    if(err > 0) {
                        alert('Niestety ale jedno lub więcej zdjęć, które próbujesz załadować są zbyt duże (dopuszczalna rozdzielczość maksymalna to 1280 x 1024).');
                    } else {
                        alert('Ok'); // form.submit();
                    }

            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fv42o0e/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's because

> Image loading is asynchronous

Image loading takes time but browser won't pause your script it would keep running code that follows.For simplicity keeping aside your code assume I have this

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){ alert('image loaded');}
img.src = "lion.jpg";
alert('hello');
```

Because loading image will always take some finite time you would always see "hello" being alerted before "image loaded" always!

Now you can probably guess where the problem was , when your `for`loop was over completing all its iteration not even the first image is done loading up till that time so `err` is 0 therefore no error message.

How to solve?
You can choose from a variety of solutions - callbacks,promise,counters etc.Assuming it's a simple application below I have used counters to solve

```
<script>         
var err = 0;
var counter = 0;

jQuery("form").submit( function( e ) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();

    var photos = document.getElementById('imgInp');
    var howmany = photos.files.length;

    var img = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {               

        if (photos.files[i]) {
            img[i] = new Image();
            img[i].src = window.URL.createObjectURL( photos.files[i] );
            counter++;
            img[i].onload = function() {
                                window.URL.revokeObjectURL( this.src );
                                if( this.width < 1281 && this.height < 1025)
                                {                                                                           

                                } else {                                                                             
                                  alert('Zdjecie jest zbyt duze');
                                  err++;
                                }
                                counter--;

                                if(counter === 0 ){
                                    if(err > 0) {
                                       alert('Niestety ale jedno lub wiecej zdjec, które próbujesz zaladowac sa zbyt duze (dopuszczalna rozdzielczosc maksymalna to 1280 x 1024).');
                                     } else {
                                         alert('Ok'); // form.submit();
                                     }
                                 }

                           };
        }                         
    }


});

</script>
```

Here is how it works : A `counter` will keep track of how many images are outstanding ie. for which `src` has been assigned but are waiting to get loaded.Increment `counter` each time you assign a `src` and decrement it each time an image gets loaded (`onload` function) also check if it was the last image to get loaded (check if `counter` is 0) if yes all images are done now run your check